# Unmarshal a particular structure as string in Golang (yaml)

Tags: go, yaml

Let's suppose I've a simple yaml like:-

```
info: []
return:
- foo.com:
    some_value:
        1.1.1.1: true
    some_value2:
        hey: hi
```

How do I get the value of `foo.com` as a string? I really don't care what structure is inside.

Using the popular library, `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`, I've tried a struct like this:-

```
type ExecuteJidResp struct {
    Info   []interface{}            `yaml:"info"`
    Return []map[string]interface{} `yaml:"return,omitempty"`
}
```

But, it errors out with:-

```
panic: yaml: line 4: found character that cannot start any token
```

Full code: https://play.golang.org/p/RJtQ9V9qGEY

Comment: Your yaml is not properly formatted. Check the leading spaces. Otherwise, it's all fine.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/hScZZth_YYQ

Comment: @oakad Thank you. Silly mistake. If you would like to answer it, I'll accept it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @oakad Would you be able to help on how to convert that `map[interface{}]interface{}` to simple yaml string?

Comment: https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/13#issuecomment-135407098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case problem the rison of error

```
panic: yaml: line 4: found character that cannot start any token [recovered]
    panic: yaml: line 4: found character that cannot start any token
```

in `yaml` formatting:

```
yourBody := `info: []
return:
- foo.com:
    some_value:
        1.1.1.1: true
    some_value2:
        hey: hi`

rightBody := `info: []
return:
- foo.com:
    some_value:
      1.1.1.1: true
    some_value2:
      hey: hi`
```

Look at *fixed* result in <kbd>[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QxiVR_KpHoc)</kbd>